# handlebars.js - Select loop based on helper output

Tags: loops, handlebars.js

In my page I have 2 *set* of `loop` in my `context.js`

```
set_1: [
    {title: 'Set 1'},
    {title: 'Set 1'},
    {title: 'Set 1'}
],

set_2: [
    {title: 'Set 2'},
    {title: 'Set 2'},
    {title: 'Set 2'}
]
```

Currently I'm doing:

```
{{#each set_1}}
   {{title}}
{{/each}}

{{#each set_2}}
   {{title}}
{{/each}}
```

What I want to achieve is based on `url parameters` be able to select which *set* to show. For instance: `domain.com/?set=1` & `domain.com/?set=2` and based on this, *right* set will be set in the `loop` and shows that.

I tried to create a helper for it as below, but it doesn't give error or show the content:

```
function getUrlParam(name) {
  var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
  return (results && results[1]) || undefined;
}
var s   = getUrlParam('set');
Handlebars.registerHelper('selectSet', function(){
  if (s == 1){
    return 'set_1'
  } else if (s == 2) {
    return 'set_2'
  } else {
    return 'set_1'
  }
});
```

and in my `html` page, I do:

```
{{#each selectSet}}
    {{title}}
{{/each}}
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this with the built-in function `lookup` that `handlebarjs` has as follow:

```
function getUrlParam(name) {
  var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
  return (results && results[1]) || undefined;
}
var s   = getUrlParam('set');
Handlebars.registerHelper('selectSet', function(){
  if (s == 1){
    return 'set_1'
  } else if (s == 2) {
    return 'set_2'
  } else {
    return 'set_1'
  }
});

// In my HTML
{{#each (lookup . (selectSet))}}
   {{name}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for such functionality to chain helpers : https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/304. If you want such a thing you have to write a helper that will chain the result produced by the first helper to the second (but forget about #each).

In the post you'll find code about writing such a helper :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('chain', function () {
    var helpers = [], value;
    $.each(arguments, function (i, arg) {
        if (Handlebars.helpers[arg]) {
            helpers.push(Handlebars.helpers[arg]);
        } else {
            value = arg;
            $.each(helpers, function (j, helper) {
                value = helper(value, arguments[i + 1]);
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
    return value;
});
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that it seems to me that your getUrlParam(name) function will probably not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChristopheThiry :) I'm going to give it a try. Regarding `getUrlParam(name)` why you think it won't work? I've tested it and works fine seems

Comment: It seems to me that the regexp is not correct but nevermind if you tested it then it works and it's not a problem